# ImageView with setBackgroundResource and setImageBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I have Imageview which i am creating it dynamically,now i am setting

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
```

What is happening is the setBackgroundResource image is stretching,as the bitmap size increases.

Why is it so?Is there any workaround?

Comment: could you first clearify me, R u setting foreground resource and background resource at a time right..? or both of them separately

Comment: first i am setting foreground(bitmap) and then background(setBackgroundResource)

Comment: yes it will stretch because to fit into the entire view..It is designed like that..If you don't want it to stretch try place your image in drawable-nodpi folder.. or create a nine patch image

Answer (score 3):

A Background resource is designed to fill up the entire View, which is why it stretched when the contents of the View are increased in size.

A possible workaround would be to use a 9-patch drawable, which only stretches are specified by you.

Another workaround would be to scale your background as your normal View Contents increase, and reset it to the new background.

Comment: scale your background as your normal View Contents ? how

Comment: Load it into a bitmap and manipulate it. It'll still be stretched, but at least now you have a chance to do it semi proportionally.

Comment: so then how to apply the background? i want it to display how the original image is ,

Comment: @Goofy You can't display how the original image is always. Sometimes, it will get stretched one way or the other. As for applying, just call setBackgroundResource() again with the new, scaled bitmap